# Unable to initialize an Inherited widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

I'm trying to use an Inherited Widget to share the same service across all the screens.

This is the **code of my Inherited Widget**:

```
class GlobalValues extends InheritedWidget {
  final AudioProvider audioProvider;

  GlobalValues({Key key, Widget child, this.audioProvider}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static AudioProvider of(BuildContext context){
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<GlobalValues>()).audioProvider;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Therefore, I **initialize** it in the Home Screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return GlobalValues(
      audioProvider: AudioProvider(),
      child: StreamBuilder<MapEntry<Position, List<MuseumCard>>>(...)
    );
  }
```

and finally I would like to **access** it from a subsequent screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    AudioProvider audioProvider = GlobalValues.of(context);
    Return Scaffold(...);
  }
```

But when the last screen is built I got this **error message**:

> The getter 'audioProvider' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: audioProvider

***I'm noticing that if I initialize the widget in the main.dart then the error doesn't show up and everything works correctly***:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GlobalValues(
      audioProvider: AudioProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(...),);
  }
```

But I would like to make it available only in a certain part of widget subtree, but don't know why it doesn't work.

Could it be due to routing between the screens? Or what other reason?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change you code while accessing as follow. You are missing to call `audioProvider` member of the class.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    AudioProvider audioProvider = GlobalValues.of(context).audioProvider;
    Return Scaffold(...);
  }
```

Comment: No, the GlobalValues.of(context) returns already the audioprovider member of the class.

Comment: No, It will return GlobalValues type. You have to access audioprovider member of it.

Comment: I cannot even access the audioprovider member, instead I can access all the methods and members of the class audioprovider, because, as I have defined the static method **of**, GlobalValues.of(context) is already the audioprovider.

Comment: are you able to use it now?

Comment: No, I'm stacked in the same situation unfortunately

Comment: You can use the `provider` library. I've used in this [project](https://github.com/Attendance-System-G14/SATS-Frontend)